# How to align a button vertically in a bootstrap column grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have been working on a web page and had to place a button in the jumbotron class. My first 8 columns are taken by the heading. In the remaining 4 columns, I have placed a button. The button appears to be positioned at the top of the columns. I want to place it at the center of the four columns. How can I do it? Please check the code below.

```html
    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header">
                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-8'>
                    <h1>Heading</h1>
                     <p>Description</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" >
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" id="feedback" onclick="window.location.href='#feedback'">feedback</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a [flexbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) inserted into one of your columns (whatever size you want).

It would work something like this:

```
.flex-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    align-items: center;
}

.flex-item { 
    max-width: 50%;
}

<header class="jumbotron"> 
        <div class="row row-header">
            <div class='col-sm-8'>
                text
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 flex-container" > 

              <button type="submit" class="flex-item btn btn-warning btn-block" id="feedback" onclick="window.location.href='#feedback'">feedback</button>

            </div> 
    </div>
</header>
```

[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/dFP81frbHk#)

Comment: Hi geostocker, thank you for replying. I have tried implementing your code in my page. But unfortunately, it's not working. The button and the position of the container have changed. The button didn't go to the center of the columns.

Comment: See the edit and the bootply. The example works, it's just that your h1 and p elements seem to create some sort of strange interaction where the browser interprets the elements a bit strangely.